# GetElementById Javascript can't access a value

Tags: javascript, get, element

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>

<style type = "text/css">
#calculator{
width:164px;
top:20%;
right:50%;
position:absolute;
border:1px black solid;
background-image:url('images.jpg');
}

#matrix
{
float:right;
border:1px black solid;
width:100px;
}
#row1{
position:relative;
width:17px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

</div>
<div id = "matrix">
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td style = "width:40px"><input type = "text" id = "one"></input></td>
    <input type = "number" id = "two"></input></td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type = "number" id = "three"></input></td>
    <input type = "number" id = "four"></input></td></tr>

</table>
<input type = "submit" value = "count" onclick = "calculate();"></input>
</form>
</div>
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
function calculate(){
var a = document.getElementById('one').value;

alert(a);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the function that i have i can't acess a any element by id properly, so that when i try to alert that varible, an alert box is empty.I had my javascript code in a head earlier,but it didn't work neither.Moving it to a body section didn't change the situation.Would be greatful if anybody could help me fix this error in a javascript, please do not write a jquery code as an alternative.Thanx.

Comment: FYI, `input` elements shouldn't have a separate `</input>`  closing tag.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed (there's a closing `</td>` tag with no opening tag), but it still works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KBv82/

Comment: What happens if you remove the spaces between '"' and '=' for attributes and don't put a separate closing tag for each `<input />` element?

Comment: Your form is being submitted. Change onclick="calculate();" to onclick="calculate();return false;". BTW, what do you want to do on the click? Calculate and then submit?

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://jsbin.com/exopat/2/edit — (at least after typing something into the field)

Comment: You really don't need to post CSS for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` for your input and change it to `button`:

```
<input id="count" type="button" value="count">
```

And use this:

```
let count = document.getElementById('count');
let a = document.getElementById('one');
count.addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
function calculate() {
  alert(a.value);
}
```

See it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam_rad/GkqEn/)

Comment: Although that's indeed a cleaner way to do it, this has nothing to do with the error he's experiencing

Comment: i don't know why but it didn't work.And why can't i use just an onClick event handler?

Comment: @user2167174, as everybody mentioned, your `html` is malformed. Try to correct it first and then test again. But this is working. I'll add a `jsFiddle` link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your button is a submit button. You should change it to a button:

```
<input type = "button" value = "count" onclick = "calculate();" />
```

Apart from that, you should revise your HTML since it's quite badly formatted and perhaps you have some things in there that could provoke errors later on.